# How can I scale a drawing from an HTML canvas and copy it to another canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

If I draw something on my canvas I would like to press save and then on save scale the image of the drawing to fit a smaller canvas in another part of the page. I think it would have something to do with the base64 src of the drawing but I'm not entirely sure how it could be done.

Suppose if the original canvas I drew on was 600px by 400px and the smaller canvas was 300px by 150px when what would the code look like?

Comment: Have you tried using **scale(float x, float y)** metod on the original canvas?

Answer (score 5):

Since the two canvases have different aspect ratios, I would use the following syntax:

[`ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

In this cases `sx`, `sy`, `sWidth` and `sHeight` specify which part of the original canvas should be copied, while `dx`, `dy`, `dWidth` and `dHeight` specify which part of the canvas they should be rendered on.

```js
const canvas1 = document.getElementById("c");
const ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
   
ctx1.beginPath()
ctx1.arc(125,125,100,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx1.stroke()

const canvas2 = document.getElementById("c1");
const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

ctx2.drawImage(canvas1,0,0,600,400,0,0,300,150);
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<canvas id="c1" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
```